# Java Printing page pops out

Tags: java, printing, dot-matrix

I m trying to print a page using dot matrix printer.Whenever i print a page even if the page is half printed the printer pops out the whole page and takes it to the new page..Please suggest something so that i can stay on the same page after printing.